# Mongoose schema property with specific values

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Here's my code:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: String,
  password: String,
  role: Something
});
```

My goal is to define the role property to have specific values ('admin', 'member', 'guest' and so on..), what's the better way to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You can do enum.

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  // ...
  , role: { type: String, enum: ['admin', 'guest'] }
}

var user = new User({
 // ...
 , role: 'admin'
});
```

Comment: nice, and then? When i want to create a specific user? **var jhon = new User(email: 'jhon@gmail.com', password: 'samplepass', role: ?);**

Comment: @cl0udw4lk3r It's still just a string, so `role: 'admin'`, for example.

Answer (score -1):

There isn't really a way that I know of to have specific values possible for role, but maybe you'd like to create multiple object types based off of a master object type, each with their own roles (and anything else you want to distinguish). For example...

```
var userSchema = function userSchema() {};
userSchema.prototype = {
  email: String,
  password: String,
  role: undefined
}
var member = function member() {};
member.prototype = new userSchema();
member.prototype.role = 'member';

var notSupposedToBeUsed = new userSchema();
var billTheMember = new member();
console.log(notSupposedToBeUsed.role); // undefined
console.log(billTheMember.role); // member
```

Another possibility is have userSchema with a constructor that easily allows you to select one of the built in values. An example...

```
var userSchema = function userSchema(role) {
    this.role = this.role[role];
    // Gets the value in userSchema.role based off of the parameter
};
userSchema.prototype = {
  email: String,
  password: String,
  role: { admin: 'admin', member: 'member', guest: 'guest' }
}
var a = new userSchema('admin');
var b = new userSchema('blah');
console.log(a.role); // 'admin'
console.log(b.role); // undefined
```

More: http://pivotallabs.com/users/pjaros/blog/articles/1368-javascript-constructors-prototypes-and-the-new-keyword

Comment: Sorry, i'm afraid that your answer dont fit well with my question, i need to know how to do that with Mongoose.js, thanks anyway!